# Dockerfile COPY command not working as expected in Docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run Nginx through docker-compose to perform load balancing over Node.js back-end. I tried to ways:

1. Writing all configurations in docker-compose.yml while passing a nginx.conf as volume as follows:

   ```
   version: '3'
   services:

   #nginx
       nginx:
           image: nginx
           container_name: books-nginx
           ports: 
               - 80:80
           links:
               - node1:node1
               - node2:node2
               - node3:node3
           volumes:
               - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

   # Back-end
       node1:
           image: node
           container_name: books-api1
           ports:
               - 3000
           volumes:
               - ./books-backend:/app
           links:
               - mongodb
           environment:
               - admin=admin-password
               - secret=strong-password
           command: bash -c "cd /app && npm install && npm start"

       node2:
           .
           .
           .

       node3:
           .
           .
           .

   # MongoDB
       mongodb:
           image: mongo
           container_name: books-mongo
           ports:
               - 27017
           volumes:
               - ./db/mongo:/data/db
   ```

In this case nginx runs perfectly.

2. Writing the configurations in a dockerfile inside 'nginx' directory and then starting it from docker-compose as follows:

nginx/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

docker-compose:

```
#nginx
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        container_name: books-nginx
        ports: 
            - 80:80
        links:
            - node1:node1
            - node2:node2
            - node3:node3
```

But in this case whenever I send a request (eg. for admin authentication) to the back-end I get the following error:

```
books-nginx | 2017/07/31 22:19:33 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/admin/authenticate" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /api/admin/authenticate HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
books-nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2017:22:19:33 +0000] "POST /api/admin/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Any ideas on how to make the second way work like the first one (with COPY command) ?

## Update

I tried creating the following dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

MAINTAINER Tamer Mohamed Bahgat

RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ADD nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD service nginx start
```

and then creating the image separtely using `docker build -t test-nginx .` and using it in docker-compose.yml using `image: test-nginx` . It worked and gave no errors.

But, using `build: .` (. is the location of the same dockerfile) still gives me the same error.

Comment: please post the contents of your dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml. Also post the actual error from the command line and the command you ran that didn't work. There simply isn't enough information here

Comment: @TamerB - I didn't see any difference in the nginx.conf file when I tested. Maybe try comparing other files in the etc/nginx dir in both scenarios? I deleted my previous answer to mark the question as unanswered.

Comment: In docker-compose.yml, the path which you are giving need to be the right path. so check with the build path. path need to have Dockerfile.